# How to load javascript variable to localpath?

Tags: javascript, php, audio

i'm using ajax in java script to get some data from database, and i want to use one of the data that i get, to load audio source in local path

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('home/loaddata'); ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data['DATA'][0]['SERVICE_ITEM']);
        console.log(data['DATA'][0]['SEQ']);
        console.log(data['DATA'][0]['KASSA_ID']); 
        var audiokassa = "<?php echo base_url("assets/Sound/Counter/counter/")?>' + data['DATA'][0]['KASSA_ID'] + '";
        var counter = new Audio(audiokassa);
        counter.play();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  })
```

i'm using codeigniter, the error that i got is unable to load the source, can you give me some ideas, to access javascript variable in php base_url? this is the error that i got.

```
GET http://localhost/queue/assets/Sound/Counter/counter/'%20+%20data['DATA'][0]['KASSA_ID']%20+%20' 400 (Bad Request)

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

Comment: You have some extra quote, which makes the concatenation not working, change it to: `var audiokassa = "<?php echo base_url("assets/Sound/Counter/counter/")?>" + data['DATA'][0]['KASSA_ID'];`

Comment: thnkyou so much it helps me